# Does SXS catalog for NR simulations have non-spinning, non-eccentric blackholes?

Tags: black-holes, computational-physics, simulations, gravitational-waves, binary-stars

I am looking for NR waveform for two non-spinning and non-eccentric black hole binary merger for small mass ratio. Somehow, on the SXS catalog website, I don't see any such description.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't get any answers on this site in a day or two, you may want to try your luck at [astronomy.se]. You may have to email the catalog owner, though I'm not sure the level of success on a response as it says it was last updated in Sept 2020.

Comment: How small is "small" for you? It becomes increasingly hard to simulate smaller and smaller mass ratios.

Comment: For mass-ratios small than 1:10 you are going to be out of luck in the (public) SXS catalog.

Answer (score 4):

All NR simulations (including the SXS simulations) have some eccentricity and some spin on each of the components. It is impossible to setup initial conditions where these vanish exactly.

However there are plenty of simulations in the [SXS catalog](https://data.black-holes.org/waveforms/catalog.html) for which the spin and eccentricity have been minimized and are essentially zero.

Here is a list of (approximately) quasicircular nonspinning 55 simulations with mass-ratio between 1-10:

{"SXS_BBH_0002", "SXS_BBH_0007", "SXS_BBH_0056", "SXS_BBH_0063", "SXS_BBH_0167", "SXS_BBH_0168", "SXS_BBH_0169", "SXS_BBH_0180", "SXS_BBH_0181", "SXS_BBH_0182", "SXS_BBH_0183", "SXS_BBH_0184", "SXS_BBH_0185", "SXS_BBH_0186", "SXS_BBH_0187", "SXS_BBH_0188", "SXS_BBH_0189", "SXS_BBH_0190", "SXS_BBH_0191", "SXS_BBH_0192", "SXS_BBH_0193", "SXS_BBH_0194", "SXS_BBH_0195", "SXS_BBH_0196", "SXS_BBH_0197", "SXS_BBH_0198", "SXS_BBH_0199", "SXS_BBH_0200", "SXS_BBH_0201", "SXS_BBH_0259", "SXS_BBH_0294", "SXS_BBH_0295", "SXS_BBH_0296", "SXS_BBH_0297", "SXS_BBH_0299", "SXS_BBH_0300", "SXS_BBH_0301", "SXS_BBH_0302", "SXS_BBH_0303", "SXS_BBH_0310", "SXS_BBH_0389", "SXS_BBH_0593", "SXS_BBH_1108", "SXS_BBH_1132", "SXS_BBH_1143", "SXS_BBH_1154", "SXS_BBH_1155", "SXS_BBH_1166","SXS_BBH_1167", "SXS_BBH_1179", "SXS_BBH_1220", "SXS_BBH_1221","SXS_BBH_1222", "SXS_BBH_1354", "SXS_BBH_1906"}

More recent simulations (higher id value) tend to have higher accuracy.